# Forcing a derived class to overload a virtual method in a non-abstract base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class, virtual-functions

I'm writing some code using a simple clone pattern, I'd like it if I were able to force derived classes to override that clone pattern, but retain the ability to use my base class.  (So I don't want to declare the clone method to be pure virtual.)

Is there anyway to enforce this restriction at the compiler level?

Comment: Even if your base class `clone` method was pure virtual that wouldn't force the child of a child to implement it.  You could achieve this if you required derived classes to include a macro of some sort in their declaration (that declared the overridden method so they have to implement it), but that's not ideal.

Comment: `virtual` implies dynamic polymorphism, which is inherantly a runtime operation, and invariants must be enforced with runtime checks. If you want compile-time operations and invariant checks, use [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) for static polymorphism instead, and something like this becomes completely trivial.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8011984/3235496

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is just no way to make this happen in C++. You can't force a non-abstract method to be overridden in child classes. However, I might note that concrete base classes should be fairly rare in C++ and you might want to reconsider your design. With more information about your overall aims we might be able to provide a better answer for your precise needs.

Comment: Ah, I was afraid of that.  Well, I am in the middle of a redesign anyway, so I'll muddle through somehow.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It has been some time I touched C++, but I do remember you can have pure virtual method with body.

```
// in header
class YourBase {
public:
  virtual Foo bar() = 0;
};

// in source
Foo YourBase::bar() {
  // a default impl
}
```

That should force the child class to override bar(), while leaving a usable impl of bar() in YourBase

Comment: the implementation doesn't help, since it's no use in using a cloning implementation that's cloning only the abstract class part. the only effect is that `YourBase` cannot be separately instantiated, since it's abstract.

Comment: maybe your "ability to use my base class" is a bit too vague.  I thought you mean ability to use the impl in base class in derived class.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't enforce at compile time that a class overrides a method of a concrete base class, but you can simply `assert` in each `clone` function implementation that the type is the type of the class where that implementation resides,

```
assert( typeid( *this ) == typeid( ThisClass ) );
```

and then run a test that exercises the cloning functionality of every class.