# how to force subclass to override a virtual function

Tags: c++

sometimes I would like to force subclass to override a function, for example:

```
class A
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
    virtual void foo() {...}
};

class C : public B
{
    //people may forget to override function foo
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Forcing Method Override In Concrete Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011984/c-forcing-method-override-in-concrete-class)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Declare the virtual function in the intermediate class also as a pure virtual function. Remember that you may provide an implementation of the function in the intermediate class even when it is declared to be pure virtual.

```
class A
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

void B::foo()
{
}

class C : public B
{
    // Now you must provide an implementation
    // if you want to create an instance of C.
};
```

This strategy works if you don't need to instantiate `B`. If you do need to instantiate `B`, a different strategy needs to be thought of. You also have to rethink your class hierarchy. All non-leaf classes should be abstract in a good design.

Thanks to @AustinMullins for providing a link to [working code](http://ideone.com/yBjf3I).

Comment: This answer assumes that the OP doesn't want to instantiate `B`. Of course, if you follow the rule that non-leaf classes should be abstract, it's all well.